# Make tag synonym or retag question?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

There is two tags that have the same meaning:

- [browser](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) with 16 tagged questions
- [web-browser](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) with 1 tagged question

One option is to retag the one question with the [browser] tag instead.

Another option is to suggest the synonym [web-browser](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) to be remapped to [browser](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) - making it work for future wrong tagging. But this option must be done by someone having a score of 5 or more on the web-browser tag (that one question) and having more then 2500 reps, witch narrows it done to 1 person only.

Which option do we use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replaced the [web-browser](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) tag from that question, we can synonymize it if it becomes commonly used but it seems unnecessary for now.